# acessar valor de field dentro do django template

Tags: html, html5, python-3.x, django, django-templates

É possível acessar os valores dentro de uma variável no django templates?

Por exemplo, tenho esse model:

```
 class Avaliacao(models.Model):
 post = models.TextField()
 data_inclusao = models.DataField()
```

no campo **post** é gravado dados uma dict, dessa forma:

```
 {'joao': ['gostei', 8], 'carla': ['nao gostei', 1] }
```

Digamos que no meu template/html, eu queira popular uma tabela, como que eu conseguiria acessar as chaves e os valores dessa string ?
Imaginem que os dados foram renderizados para a variável dados:

```
{% for avaliacao in dados %}
 {{ avaliacao.post }}
{% endfor %}
```

A saída esperar seria:

```html
<html>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
<th>Nome</th>
<th>Avaliacao: </th>
<th>Nota: </th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
   <tr>
<td>JOAO</td>
<td>GOSTEI</td>
<td>8</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
<td>CARLA</td>
<td>NAO GOSTEI</td>
<td>1</td>
    <tr>

</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Um `TextField` guarda texto, não `dict`... Se você está serializando o dict antes de salvar no banco, basta deserializar e usar como dict...

Comment: @fernandosavio eu sei disso, infelizmente os dados são gravados da forma que mencionei. O que precisaria era pegar essas strings. e formar novas variáveis. Se no template não for possível el, você sabe como posso criar uma função no model, para poder chamar a função  no template ?

Comment: Você não especifica qual é o formato da serialização, mas aparentemente é JSON.. Basta usar o [módulo `json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) do python. O SOPt já tem [bastante conteúdo sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpython%5d%20json%20is%3aquestion), dê uma olhada.

Comment: boa, vou olhar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver criando uma função no model que retorna os dados em formato Json, dessa forma consigo chamar a função o no template e navegar da dict.

## MODEL

```
class Avaliacao(models.Model):
post = models.TextField()
data_inclusao = models.DataField()
```

## FUNÇÃO NO MODEL

```
@property
def post_dict(self):
    try:
        return json.loads(self. post)
    except ValueError:
        return {}
```

## VIEW

```
 queryset = Avaliacao.objects.all()
{'dados': queryset}
```

## TEMPLATE

```
{% for avaliacao in dados.post_dict.items %}
 {{ avaliacao.0 }}
 {{ avaliacao.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Como o tipo de dados é um dictionary, podes aceder assim:

```
{% for key, values in dados.items %}
    {{ key }} 
    {% for item in values %}
        {{ item }} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

NOTA: No primeiro for, irás aceder ao valor da key do teu dict, como é um dict tens key/value, no value como tens um array, precisas de outro for para percorrer todos os valores deste.